# How do I change the dropdown icon in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, bootstrap-5

I need to change the default icon that appears in the Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu to a Font Awesome character.

I've read the documentation but there is nothing of use there. I have tried to override the CSS to no avail.

How do I change the dropdown icon in Bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I assume you already have the link rel="stylesheet" in your html head.
This is the most recent that you should use, but I tried with a older version and also worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
```

Then I grabed the Bootstrap 5 dropdown and added a **custom-dropdown** class:

```
<div class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown button
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And then in your css file you create the following:

```
.custom-dropdown .dropdown-toggle::after {
  content: '\f1b2'; /* Replace this with the desired Font Awesome icon code */
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'; /* Specify the Font Awesome font-family */
  font-weight: 900; /* Adjust the font weight if needed */
  border-top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have never used font awesome before but without using border-top 0 I saw a white bar above the icon. That's why I used bordertop and vertical align to align the icon.

Or you can simply do this in your css:

```
.custom-dropdown .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

And then use the icon like this:

```
<div class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown button
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-cube"></i>
                </button>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Check if everything is working as you wanting after changing the icon and if yes you can mark the answer as correct :)